# How to calculate factorial with input of very large numbers in Python?

Tags: python

I'm currently having a school assignment on calculating factorials in Python. Specifically, the user will enter a positive integer N, and then I would have to calculate the sum of the factorials from 1! to N! with the formula:

**F(N) = 1! +2! + ... + N!**

This is simple, so I wrote this code. I also did multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
import math
import sys

def get_input():
    N = int(input("N = "))
    
    return N

def calc_factorial(N: int):
    factorials = [] # List data type
    
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        factorials.append(math.factorial(i))
        
    return factorials

def sum_factorial(factorials_calculated_arr):
    summary = 0
    
    for elem in factorials_calculated_arr:
        summary += elem
    
    return summary

def calc_factorial_interface(N: int, return_result):
    getcontext().prec = 900000
    
    return_result.put(sum_factorial(calc_factorial(N)))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        N = get_input()
        
        pool_result = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
        result_manager = mp.Manager()
        
        result_ret = result_manager.Queue()
        
        pool_result.apply_async(calc_factorial_interface, (N, result_ret))
        
        result = result_ret.get()
        
        # in python 3.9.4, we have this error when insert this line:
        # module 'sys' has no attribute 'set_int_max_str_digits'
        # so we need check python version before we use the command:
        # sys.set_int_max_str_digits()
        if sys.version_info >= (3, 11, 4):
            sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)
        
        print(f"F({N}) = {str(result)}")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{e}")
```

Of course, this code works. But still the problem I have here is the runtime. Even if I used `math.factorial()`

I tested the inputs and this is the time to run them:

```
N = 5739 -> Run time: 19.960s
N = 10001 -> Run time: 67.721s
N = 12345 -> Run time: 109.549s
N = 18000 -> Run time: 406.741s
N = 21000 -> Run time: 579.083s
```

The exercise requires the program to be completed within 10 seconds.

So, is there a way to calculate the factorial with very large numbers in Python quickly?

Comment: I think it would be a wise idea to not use the `math.factorial` function, but calculating it yourself. Remember that n! = (n-1)! * n, so you only need _one_ multiplication to get the next term instead of n. E.g. to calculate 10!, you take the result of 9! and multiply by 10.

Comment: If you are taking quite a big number, are you taking its modulus with any constant?

Comment: You should be using the SciPy scipy.special.gamma function to return a double and memoizing results: gamma(n) = (n-1)!.  What you call "simple" is naive.

Comment: @duffymo Python ints are arbitrary precision, so an exact result can be obtained with integer math, whereas using doubles will suffer from precision errors.

Comment: Small note: it may be required as per your assignment, but the `get_input` function is really not necessary if the function is literally one line.

Comment: Additionally to what @BRemmelzwaal said, there's no need to build a list with each term in the sequence, then sum them at the end. You can calculate one term at a time and keep a running sum.

Comment: *"...the factorial will be calculated..."*: what you present is not the factorial, but a **sum of** factorials. Can you update your question to make it consistent?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you think multiprocessing would be helpful in the program you've written?

Comment: @trincot sorry for the confusion, I have updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To optimise the calculation of your function **F(N) = 1! +2! + ... + N!** we can benefit from a couple of things:

1. As @BRemmelzwaal said, rather than calculating each factorial "from scratch" we can use the recurrence relation `p! = p(p-1)!` to calculate each value quickly from the previous one in the series. This substantially improves speed.
2. Rather than making a list containing each term of the series, we can compute a running sum. This decreases memory usage, though without a massive speedup.

Comparing a few different approaches...

a) `sum_fac_loop` does the calculation in a simple Python for-loop (no imports), using the fact that `p! = p(p-1)!` and keeping a running sum.

b) `sum_fac_itertools` uses `itertools.accumulate` to calculate each factorial (again using the identity `p! = p(p-1)!` and taking advantage of the fact that we already know `(p-1)!` each time.)

c) `sum_math_factorial_gen` sums the result of `math.factorial` for each value `1..N`. By using a generator comprehension, we avoid creating an explicit list.

d) `sum_math_factorial_list` is similar to (c) but builds a list containing each factorial.

...we find that approaches (a) and (b) - which take advantage of optimisation (1) avoid calculating each factorial individually - easily beat your 10 second benchmark, while (c) and (d) are much slower for large `N`.

```
import itertools
import math
import operator
from time import perf_counter

def sum_fac_loop(n):
    fac = 1
    tot = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        fac *= i   # calculates i!
        tot += fac # calculates running sum, 1! + 2! + ... + i!
    return tot

def sum_fac_itertools(n):
    return sum(itertools.accumulate(range(1, n+1), operator.mul))

def sum_math_factorial_gen(n):
    return sum(math.factorial(i) for i in range(1, n+1))

def sum_math_factorial_list(n):
    return sum([math.factorial(i) for i in range(1, n+1)])

funcs = {'(a) Loop using recurrence relation': sum_fac_loop,
         '(b) sum(itertools.accumulate)': sum_fac_itertools,
         '(c) sum(math.factorial) generator': sum_math_factorial_gen,
         '(d) sum(math.factorial) list': sum_math_factorial_list}

for n in (5739, 10001, 12345, 18000, 21000):
    print(f'n = {n}')
    for desc, func in funcs.items():
        results = []
        start = perf_counter()
        results.append(func(n))
        end = perf_counter()
        print(f'{desc}: {end-start:.4f}s')

    # Verify results match
    assert all(r == results[0] for r in results[1:])
    print()
```

Output:

```
n = 5739
(a) Loop using recurrence relation: 0.0181s
(b) sum(itertools.accumulate): 0.0098s
(c) sum(math.factorial) generator: 1.4614s
(d) sum(math.factorial) list: 1.4332s

n = 10001
(a) Loop using recurrence relation: 0.0325s
(b) sum(itertools.accumulate): 0.0335s
(c) sum(math.factorial) generator: 7.5657s
(d) sum(math.factorial) list: 6.9344s

n = 12345
(a) Loop using recurrence relation: 0.0887s
(b) sum(itertools.accumulate): 0.0824s
(c) sum(math.factorial) generator: 13.7223s
(d) sum(math.factorial) list: 13.2114s

n = 18000
(a) Loop using recurrence relation: 0.0991s
(b) sum(itertools.accumulate): 0.1104s
(c) sum(math.factorial) generator: 37.7014s
(d) sum(math.factorial) list: 38.2374s

n = 21000
(a) Loop using recurrence relation: 0.1511s
(b) sum(itertools.accumulate): 0.1421s
(c) sum(math.factorial) generator: 58.9403s
(d) sum(math.factorial) list: 59.9885s
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that 21000! generates a number that contains more than 80,000 digits which is more than can be handled in a default Python environment.

But there is a system setting that can be used to overcome this constraint.

Here's an implementation of F(N) with timings:

```
from sys import set_int_max_str_digits
from time import perf_counter

def F(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('F: n must be greater than zero')
    r = 1
    f = 2
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        r += f 
        f *= i+1
    return r

# this is only necessary if you intend to convert a result from F(N) to a string
set_int_max_str_digits(100_000)

N = 5739, 10001, 12345, 18000, 21000

for n in N:
    start = perf_counter()
    F(n)
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f'F({n})', f'{end-start:.4f}s')
```

**Output:**

```
F(5739) 0.0109s
F(10001) 0.0352s
F(12345) 0.0492s
F(18000) 0.1049s
F(21000) 0.1429s
```

**Note:**

No multiprocessing here because it seems irrelevant

Comment: With `n=21000` I think this calculates `21000!`, rather than OP's calculation of `1! + 2! + ... + 21000!` ? It's the need to calculate all those factorials that gives an advantage to solutions that use the relation `n! = n(n-1)!` rather than calculating every factorial "from scratch".

Comment: @slothrop The question is rather confusing. I quote "user will enter a positive integer N, and then the factorial will be calculated by the formula:

F(N) = 1! +2! + ... + N! " Of course, that is **not** the formula for calculating a factorial. So I wasn't sure if she was trying to calculate N! or the sum of factorials in the range 1! -> N!

Comment: @DarkKnight sorry I'm late. You are right, the problem is forcing me to sum the factorials from 1! to N!, and I have to write that algorithm so that it has a runtime <= 10 seconds

Comment: @DuyThanh As you can see from my answer the function F() does that and in the worst case achieves completion in 0.14s. Of course the performance will vary depending on your hardware